# How to save image in S3 using pre-signed url and getting back the saved image url to save in Database

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am using node as backend and I was able to save image in s3 but when i use getObject presigned url i get back url which download file but file is not an image it has local file location

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem, or maybe there are 2 of them?
1. do you trying to get the saved image URL to download it later on?
2. do the file type that you are downloading doesn't match its type as an image?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are facing two problems:

1. You want to get a download URL link of the file you just uploaded.
2. The file type that you download doesn't match its actual type.

Let's answer one at the time:

1. Pre-signed URLs are temporary (time manners) URLs with restricted access, therefore you can't get a permanent download URL link after you upload your object, what you can do is to generate a pre-signed URL every time you want to access it. If the object ACL is `public` you can access it using this template `https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key name`.
2. If you upload an object with a specified `content-type` it will be downloaded with the same content-type, so as I see it, by adding `Content-Type` header to your pre-signed URL creation & upload request, your problem will be solved.